# How to reference One Contract Into Another Contract In Solidity

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain, contract-deployment, truffle-console

I have 3 contracts that I am trying to deploy.2 are dependent on the third one, but for some reason, I am unable to call function from the other contract. Below is my code.

**ERC20 Token**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.0;

// Define your Smart Contract with the "Contract" keyword and an empty constructor
contract ERC20 {

    string public name = "Token";
    string public symbol = "Symbol";
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    // mapping of Balances
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    constructor(uint256 _initialSupply) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
        totalSupply = _initialSupply;
    }

}
```

**NFT Market**

```
contract NFTMarket is ReentrancyGuard {
  using Counters for Counters.Counter;
  Counters.Counter private _itemIds;
  Counters.Counter private _itemsSold;

  address payable owner;
  uint256 listingPrice = 0.025 ether;

  constructor() {
    owner = payable(msg.sender);
  }
}
```

**NFT Contract**

```
    // Import the ERC20 Token contract
    import "./ERC20.sol";
    
    
    contract NFT is ERC721URIStorage {
        using Counters for Counters.Counter;
        Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
        address contractAddress;
    
        // Declaring the ERC20 token contract variable
        ERC20 public tokenContract;
    
        constructor(address marketplaceAddress, ERC20 _tokenContract) ERC721("My NFT", "MNFT") {
            contractAddress = marketplaceAddress;
    
            // Assign Token Contract Reference to the NFT Contract
            tokenContract = _tokenContract;

  }
}
```

**Deployer**

```
const ERC20 = artifacts.require("ERC20");
const NFT = artifacts.require("NFT");
const NFTMarket = artifacts.require("NFTMarket");

module.exports = function (deployer, network, accounts) {

    deployer.then(async () => {

        // Pass initial supply as argument of the deployer.
        await deployer.deploy(ERC20, 1000000); // 1000000 NZT tokens

        await deployer.deploy(NFTMarket);

        await deployer.deploy(NFT, NFTMarket.address, ERC20.address);

    })
};
```

**Testing & Console**

```
const balance = await tokenNFT.tokenContract().methods.balanceOf(await tokenNFT.address).call()
const balance2 = await tokenNFT.tokenContract.methods.balanceOf(await tokenNFT.address)
const balance3 = await tokenNFT.tokenContract.balanceOf(await tokenNFT.address)
```

Non of these returns anything. My NFT contract is not able to call the ERC20 token functions. What am I doing wrong here. Please help me solve this, as I have been stuck for multiple hours now.

Amicably,
Christian

Comment: Can you also explain what are you expecting to be returned? are this contracts complete of fif you just included a piece of them?

Comment: The contracts are not complete. I am simply trying to call a function from the ERC20 contract inside my NFT contract. I could not post the entire code, just the ones I think are causing problems.
Thanks for your reply @JulissaDC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case those cases dont work because your `NFT` contract does not inherits from `ERC20` so the only places you can use those functions is where you declared instances of the `ERC20` contract. For example:

This is your `NFT` contract:

```
 // Import the ERC20 Token contract
    import "./ERC20.sol";
    
    
    contract NFT is ERC721URIStorage {
        using Counters for Counters.Counter;
        Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
        address contractAddress;
    
        // Declaring the ERC20 token contract variable
        ERC20 public tokenContract;
    
        constructor(address marketplaceAddress, ERC20 _tokenContract) ERC721("My NFT", "MNFT") {
            contractAddress = marketplaceAddress;
    
            // Assign Token Contract Reference to the NFT Contract
            tokenContract = _tokenContract;
            }
    function RandomFunction() public returns(uint256){
    //EXAMPLE OF USING ERC20 FUNCTION
        return tokenContract.balanceOf(msg.sender);
    }

}
```

As you can see inside a `RandomFunction` you can call any ERC20 function using the instance of the token you created on deploy using the contructor. But you cannot call those functions from the outside.

Comment: You were right @Julissa. I knew it all along, I was just doing it wrong. Trying to call a function on the console, instead of defining it first inside my smart contract, just like you did with `RandomFunction()`. Thanks I appreciate your help.