# >> Using an NFT to Access a Multisig <<

Tags: nft, gnosis-safe, multisignature, dao, governance

I would like to create a multisig wallet that allows access to wallets that hold a specific NFT.

Gnosis safe allows access to specific wallets, but I want this process to be even easier by enabling access to any wallet that holds the NFT.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Gnosis sage is a better project but it contains a lot of boilerplate and it's an end to end solution instead of just the contract.
If what you are looking for is just the contract to get started, you can look to it's predecessor:
https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWallet.sol
(This repo is no longer maintained, use only as a template, or use directly the gnosis safe code)

The multisig contract works by checking ownership which is kept in an array and mapping.
https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWallet.sol#L31

Instead of doing that, you can just reference a specific erc721 smart contract instance in the contract:
[How to reference One Contract Into Another Contract In Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/115095/how-to-reference-one-contract-into-another-contract-in-solidity)

And whenever you check for an owner, use the balanceOf, to check if the user has NFTs in that collection, or ownerOf, if you are looking for specific NFTs:
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L62

So for example:

```
    function confirmTransaction(uint transactionId)
    public
    ownerExists(msg.sender)
    transactionExists(transactionId)
    notConfirmed(transactionId, msg.sender)
{
    confirmations[transactionId][msg.sender] = true;
    Confirmation(msg.sender, transactionId);
    executeTransaction(transactionId);
}
```

Would turn into something kinda like

```
function confirmTransaction(uint transactionId)
    public
    require(erc721.balanceOf(msg.sender)>0, "You need to own an NFT to confirm transactions in this multisig")
    transactionExists(transactionId)
    notConfirmed(transactionId, msg.sender)
{
    confirmations[transactionId][msg.sender] = true;
    Confirmation(msg.sender, transactionId);
    executeTransaction(transactionId);
}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you so so much for this answer!

I am still learning Solidity, so I can only understand about 50% of what you said here, but I will work hard to understand this better and will reply here if I have any issues (or if it works correctly).